# XSLT Generating Folders

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am trying to parse an XML file into smaller XML files and place them into folders. The folders get generated based on some of the elements in XML.

How do I generating folders in XSLT? I was able to generate files using xsl:result-document, but so far I had no luck with finding how to generate folders.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a path in result-document, i.e. <xsl:result-document href="folder/toc.html"> ? I am not sure if that would even work, but I can ask anyway.

Comment: @Sorrow +1 didn't know that was possible

Comment: Can you specify if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - <xsl:result-document/> may not help if you are using the older version of XSLT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to create folders specifically, just supply full desired path like `folder1/doc1.xml`. [For example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipmultxsl/index.html):

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <testrun run="test1">
        <test name="foo" pass="true" />
        <test name="bar" pass="true" />
        <test name="baz" pass="true" />
    </testrun>
    <testrun run="test2">
        <test name="foo" pass="true" />
        <test name="bar" pass="false" />
        <test name="baz" pass="false" />
    </testrun>
    <testrun run="test3">
        <test name="foo" pass="false" />
        <test name="bar" pass="true" />
        <test name="baz" pass="false" />
    </testrun>
</tests>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//testrun">
<xsl:variable name="filename"
  select="concat('output1/',@run,'.html')" />
<xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
    <html><body>
        <xsl:value-of select="@run"/>
    </body></html>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably implementation-dependent, but if you use Saxon then `<xsl:result-document href="foo/bar/baz/sample.xml"/>` will create the folders if they don't already exist.